# Increase the maximum file size to be ingested in the Azure Data Explorer (ADX, Kusto)

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I am currently ingesting multiple TB of data into the DB of an Azure Data Explorer Cluster (ADX aka Kusto DB). In total, I iterate over about 30k files. Some of them are a few kB, but some as big as many GB.

With some big files I am running into errors due to their file sizes:

```py
FailureMessage(
    {
        ...
        "Details":"Blob size in bytes: '4460639075' has exceeded the size limit allowed for ingestion ('4294967296' B)",
        "ErrorCode":"BadRequest_FileTooLarge",
        "FailureStatus":"Permanent",
        "OriginatesFromUpdatePolicy":false,
        "ShouldRetry":false
    })
```

Is there anything I can do to increase the allowed ingestion size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a non-configurable 4GB limit.

you should split your source file(s) (ideally, so that each file has between 100MB-1GB of *uncompressed* data).

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-best-practices#optimizing-for-throughput

Comment: Mhm, that is unfortunate. My files are compressed (gzip) and yet over this 4GB threshold. Uncompressing then would blow them up by a factor of ~20. Speaking of TB of _compressed_ data, this seems not suitable.

Comment: ADX ingestion limitations relate to the _uncompressed_ data size, so if you are over 4GB _compressed_, we have a problem. Even if you were able to override the size limit, that ingest operation would either run out of memory or out of time.